# How can I prevent against the HiddenWasp trojan?

Tags: security, ip, malware

As people probably know by now, some hackers released a trojan "HiddenWasp" into the Linux world.

Article from Intezer:
https://www.intezer.com/blog-hiddenwasp-malware-targeting-linux-systems/

So far I have not seen what the initial cause of getting infected is and how to prevent it, but I've read something about looking for a user "**sftp**" which is created by the trojan script, and then looking inside **/etc/rc.local** since it is supposed to only have "**exit 0**". The script appends some code to that file apparently.

There is also a hint to look for "**ld.so**" files that don't have string "**/etc/ld.so.preload**"

They mention that prevention can be done by blocking Command-and-Control IP addresses detailed on the article site.

How do i block off specific IP-addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You would [configure iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) (see your specific distro documentation) to block connections to the IP-addresses in that article, however it is likely these Command-and-Control addresses would frequently change.

There are also options such as configuring [AppArmour](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse) for the specific distro you are using, or security focused desktop distros such as [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) that run browsers and other programs in their own  container, or other sandboxing programs such as [nsjail](http://nsjail.com/) to possibly prevent infection however since the article indicates the attack vector is not yet known it's not immediately clear the best way to defend against HiddenWasp.